# Magento $_product->getData('small_image') does not work

Tags: image, magento, product

This was working in 1.5, but after upgrading to 1.9 it does not work anymore.

It is called in the template with

```
$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(191,177).
```

Inside `__toString()` is called and statement

```
$model->setBaseFile($this->getProduct()->getData($model->getDestinationSubdir()))
```

but `this->getProduct()->getData('small_image')` gives no result anymore. So finally the placeholder is used.

The normal image in the product page is still working.

I have only updated the database and took the fresh 1.9 version to start over with extensions. If I have no extensions, this still does not work!

`small_image` is in fact an attribute. There are many attributes in the database for a product but not used anymore (not related to an extension for the moment), maybe this is the problem, but there are no errors in the log.

Comment: At which template file you are using this call?? Are u sure  you are receiving the $_product object??

Comment: Hi Pavan, it is an own template as used in 1.5, everything still works but not the small images (list.phmtl). Programs like Image.php (helper) are still the same in 1.9. I go to find out now why the normal images in the product page are working to find the differences .. everything was going well, this is now a stopper and have to be solved .. we see .. yes I am receiving the $_product object because fields like 'name' I receive with ->getData('name') ..

Comment: Finally solved, but not really for my feelings. When I create a product again with 'sku' specially for my images, then I can retrieve images like 'small_image' and 'thumbnail' but other fields I could already got. This product was created by an collection, in the product info screen it is probably also new created as object .. maybe it has to do something with attributes (sometimes the source models are missing for old attributes and gives an error in the collection, but not reported in the logs, maybe later when I remove all unused attributes this error will really solved) ..